# json.net object with two nullable properties serialize to single property

Tags: json.net

I want to use json.net to serialize options for jquery ui widgets, e.g. jquery accordion.

But accordion has a property **active** which can be one of the following :

an integer 0 based which defines an active tab,

a boolean, when set to false, will collapse all accordions.

I was thinking to create 2 nullable .NET properties :

```
int? Active

bool? IsActive
```

if Active is not null it should be serialized as an integer with property name **active**,
if IsActive is not null it should be serialize as a boolean with the same name **active**.
.Net code would make sure that only one of them can be not null.

But when I put [JsonProperty("active")] on both properties, it does not work... any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty with your current approach is that having those two fields won't work as you cannot mark them both `[JsonProperty("active")]`. My first attempt was to define the class as follows:

```
class Accordion
{
    [JsonProperty("active")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ActiveTabConverter))]
    public int Active { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("active")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ActiveTabConverter))]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Which causes an exception (I presume you got this one as well) because I used `[JsonProperty("active")]` on two properties. Removing one of these attributes did not work either: there was no exception, but the field the attribute was removed from was never deserialized.

What did work was the following:

```
class Accordion
{
    [JsonProperty("active")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ActiveTabConverter))]
    public int Active { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Active > -1;
        }
    }

    public Accordion()
    {
        this.Active = -1;
    }
}
```

Note that there are still two fields, but only one of them will be deserialized. The `IsActive` is a helper property. The convention I have followed here is that `Active` values greater than 0 indicate the open accordion tab, while -1 is equivalent to receiving `false` from the JSON.

```
class ActiveTabConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(int) || objectType == typeof(bool);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = JValue.ReadFrom(reader);

        if (value.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<int>(reader);
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        int item = (int)value;

        if (item == -1)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(false);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue(item);
        }

        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

This class is responsible for deserializing and serializing the `Active` value.

I used the following to code to serialize/deserialize. Note that the JSON actually comes from a jQuery accordion. It is way overkill for the one property in question, but I thought it best to use real data.

```
string json1 = "{\"disabled\":false,\"create\":null,\"active\":2,\"animate\":300,\"collapsible\":false,\"event\":\"click\",\"header\":\"> li > :first-child,> :not(li):even\",\"heightStyle\":\"auto\",\"icons\":{\"activeHeader\":\"ui-icon-triangle-1-s\",\"header\":\"ui-icon-triangle-1-e\",\"headerSelected\":\"ui-icon-triangle-1-s\"},\"activate\":null,\"beforeActivate\":null,\"navigation\":false,\"autoHeight\":true,\"clearStyle\":false,\"fillSpace\":false,\"change\":null,\"changestart\":null,\"animated\":\"slide\"}";
string json2 = "{\"disabled\":false,\"create\":null,\"active\":false,\"animate\":300,\"collapsible\":true,\"event\":\"click\",\"header\":\"> li > :first-child,> :not(li):even\",\"heightStyle\":\"auto\",\"icons\":{\"activeHeader\":\"ui-icon-triangle-1-s\",\"header\":\"ui-icon-triangle-1-e\",\"headerSelected\":\"ui-icon-triangle-1-s\"},\"activate\":null,\"beforeActivate\":null,\"navigation\":false,\"autoHeight\":true,\"clearStyle\":false,\"fillSpace\":false,\"change\":null,\"changestart\":null,\"animated\":\"slide\"}";

Accordion accordion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Accordion>(json1);
string serializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accordion);

accordion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Accordion>(json2);
serializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accordion);
```

Comment: You're solution is ok, but I was looking (if possible of course) for a more generic approach, as I wish to serialize options for other jquery ui widgets as well. I'm a bit afraid I will have to add a great number of convertors, for all different cases.

Comment: The number of converters depends on the other widgets you would like to serialize - the only reason for this approach is the `active` property being both boolean and integer: you may not necessarily have this problem with other widgets. Besides, you could quite happily reused the `ActiveTabConverter` in other boolean/integer scenarios; it isn't specific to the `Active` property.

Comment: unfortunately, there are several properties in the jquery widgets which accept multiple data types, not only integer/boolean